# How to check if VARCHAR contains at least one Uppercase letter - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I want to check if my `VARCHAR(30) code` contains more than 10 letters and has at least one uppercase letter. Here is how I wrote this:

```
 code VARCHAR(30) CHECK(char_length(code) > 10 AND code LIKE '?=.*[A-Z]')
```

I used `?=.*[A-Z]` regex with positive look ahead to check if there is uppercase letter in my code.

But I repeatedly get:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "vouchercode" violates check constraint "vouchercode_code_check"
```

Is my regex wrong?

Comment: Use lowercase(code)!=code instead of like part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a case sensitive regular expression.  That would be:

```
check (code ~ '[A-Z]')
```

By default, `~` is case-sensitive.  You would use `~*` for the case-insensitive version.